# How can I get external js file functions in scope for other external js functions in nuxt?

Tags: javascript, nuxt.js

I have a bunch of js files that do various d3 work, in each of them I have generic handlers, like on mousemove etc. I have these generic handlers in one file.

I am importing them into my vue page using:

```
<script>
import * as d3 from "d3";
import { viewmousemove } from "@/assets/javascript/d3ObjectGenericHandler";
import createGrid from "@/assets/javascript/transformations/Grid";
...
```

My generic handler has:

```
export function viewmousemove(event) {
  const x = Math.round(d3.pointer(event)[0]);
  const y = Math.round(d3.pointer(event)[1]);
  document.getElementById("lblCoord").innerHTML =
    "C [" + x + "," + (1800 - y) + "]";
}
```

And in Grid.js I have:

```
export default function (container, object) {
  var grid = container.append("g").attr("id", "Grid");
  .on("mousemove", viewmousemove);
...
```

But when I run the code I get the following error:

Uncaught (in promise) ReferenceError: viewmousemove is not defined

If I comment out the line .on("mousemove", viewmousemove); then the code runs as expected, the d3 lines are drawn etc.

What do I need to do to get this to work?

Comment: Did you `import { viewmousemove } .. ` inside Grid.js ?

Comment: Thanks, I have now done that, but now I get d3 is not defined in my viewmousemove function.

Comment: Can you alter the signature of `function (container, object) ` to take a 3rd argument `handler` ? Thus passing it in as an argument rather than relying on it's definition to already be in the current scope.

Comment: Excellent, that works. Thanks. Do you want to add that as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to carljdp I have got this to work be implementing the following:

I have changed Grid.js to start:

```
export default function (container, object, viewmousemove) {
  var grid = container.append("g").attr("id", "Grid");
  .on("mousemove", viewmousemove);
...
```

I now call this from my vue file with:

```
createSETGrid(
  this.svgContainer,
  this.pages[this.selectedPage],
  viewmousemove
);
```

And at the top of the d3ObjectGenericHandler I have put:

```
import * as d3 from "d3";
```

This works, though it would be good if I could just import these and they operate as it works in C# webforms. Maybe if I loaded the scripts into the body it may work.

Comment: regarding "Maybe if I loaded the scripts into the body it may work." - it all depends on whether the thing you want to call is within scope when you call it.

It's my understanding that anything attached to `window` should be available from anywhere, which could work, but also lead to unexpected results if anything can call it.